# Using Many-to-One Relationships in Spring Data JDBC

Tags: spring, database, jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc

**Note**: I am aware of [this similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64830657/11421485), however its accepted answer does not help me.

---

I have the following SQL tables in my schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses
(
    id  VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY,
    street VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    province VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    zip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    purchase_order VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase_orders
(
    id VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (address) REFERENCES addresses(id)
);
```

and I have the following Kotlin data classes:

```kotlin
@Table("PURCHASE_ORDERS")
data class PurchaseOrder(
    @Id val id: String?,
    val lastName: String,
    val firstName: String,
    val status: Status,
    val address: Address
) {
    enum class Status {
        PENDING,
        APPROVED,
        REJECTED
    }
}

@Table("ADDRESSES")
data class Address(
    @Id val id: String?,
    val street: String,
    val province: String,
    val country: String,
    val zip: String,
    val phone: String?,
)
```

Each `PurchaseOrder` has one `Address`, but one `Address` may have multiple `PurchaseOrder`s.

I am aware that Spring Data JDBC doesn't support this type of relationship, so how would I refactor my tables or classes to actually get it to work? I saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956237/11421485) but it doesn't help me much since the link it mentions only describes many-to-many relationships as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can try switching to spring-data-jpa (which uses hibernate by default). Then ManyToOne relationships would work: `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "address") val address: Address?`. I understand that switching may not be a solution, however, so I did not post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The @Table annotation is not part of Spring JDBC.

If you are going to use Spring JDBC, and not a JPA or ORM frame work then you write INSERTs to each of the two tables.   Make sure @Transction support is enabled so if an insert fails on one it rolls back both INSERTS.